# Conditional import python in notebook

Tags: python, import, module, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to modify the import names of a module depending on whether I'm in a notebook or not.
I tried something like

**api.py**

```
is_notebook = False
if is_notebook:
    from tqdm import tnrange as trange
    from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
else:
    from tqdm import trange
    from tqdm import tqdm
```

and in the cell of the notebook I would do:

```
import api
api.is_notebook = True
```

But it does not seem to work.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: I don't have any error but is does not modify the import.

Comment: 1. Did u try "try-except block" ?
2. Did u debug code for the imports; try it by adding a print statement in try and except blocks ?

Comment: I don't see your point as I don't have import errors

Answer (score 0):

I think we can achieve the same by using an intermediate file abc.py like this:

## contents of abc.py

```
is_notebook = False
if is_notebook:
   from tqdm import tnrange as trange
   from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
else:
   from tqdm import trange
   from tqdm import tqdm
```

then in the product code try like this:

```
from abc import trange
from abc import tqdm
```

You will get the proper code for trange and tqdm.

Answer (score 0):

api.py

```
def imports(is_notebook):
    if is_notebook:
        from tqdm import tnrange as trange
        from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
    else:
        from tqdm import trange
        from tqdm import tqdm
```

after importing the api.py call this function:

```
api.imports(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hacky solution relying on the way python module import works, and it will probably break very easily. My apologies.

In your code, you are setting notebook to True only after the module api is imported, so it will have no effect. However, neither can you access the notebook variable before the module is loaded, since you have no reference.
The solution is to make a third module, let's call it "notebook.py" which is just a empty text file.

In your main, you first call "import notebook" to create a global instance of the notebook module. Then set the notebook property in that module to true or false.

Next, import api. From api, also import the notebook module. Python is smart and simply gives you a reference to the same object, instead of loading the module again. Now you can use this modules "notebook" property to check what submodules to load.

The final coad will look like this:

notebook.py:

```
#no actual code here
```

main.py

```
import notebook
notebook.notebook=True
import api
```

api.py

```
import notebook
if notebook.notebook:
    from tqdm import tnrange as trange
    from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
else:
    from tqdm import trange
    from tqdm import tqdm
```